# Get array from C# string property

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm retrieving a row from a database that has an attribute which is a comma separated list of ID's

`1,2,3,4,5`

In my POCO is it possible to do something like this to get an array back?

```
public string SomeIDs 
{
    get 
    {
        return SomeIDs.split(',');
    }
    set;
}
```

Edit: Sorry, to clarify, I am setting with a string and want to return a string array

Comment: Well not quite like that, no. Your property getter is calling itself... one time expecting it to be a string, and one time trying to return a string array. Oh, and `split` should be `Split`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have a setter which accepts a `string` and returns a `string[]`. You'll need to expose one property which accepts a `string`, and a read-only property (as below) which returns a parsed array from that string:

```
private static readonly string[] emptyIds = new string[0];
public string SomeIds { get; set; }
public string[] ParsedIds 
{
    get 
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeIds) ? SomeIds.Split(',') : 
                                                emptyIds;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Comment: But how can I set it with a string?

Comment: @hammy35 Why would you want to set it? You said you return it as a concatenated string. What sense would that make?

Comment: You would need a separate property (possibly write-only) of type `string` to do that.  You can't have different read/write types for a single property

Comment: When I get the data from the database it's a string "1,2,3,4,5"

Comment: Then you'll need to have two separate properties.

Comment: I would add a guard clause in the get to ensure that SomeIds is not null and has a value before splitting it. Just by adding if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty()) and returning an empty array if it fails the check.

Comment: @RobKing You got it :)

Comment: `Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToArray()` is a bit overkill IMHO: no need to create an iterator here. You could use `new String[] {}` or even better have a `static readonly String[] EmptyIds = new String[] {}` and return a  reference to it.

Comment: You guys are really nit-picky :). Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need:

```
private string _ids;
public string[] SomeIDs
{
    get { return _ids.Split(','); }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try this:

```
private string _someIDs;
public object SomeIDs
{
  get { return _someIDs.Split(','); }
  set { _someIDs = value as string; }
}
```